# gdal.warp in Python script

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I've a .tif file in EPSG:3426 and i'd like to convert it in UTM, zone 33, scale: meters.
In gdal I use:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m" image_input.tif image_utm.tif
```

but in my Python script I try:

```
input= "C:\\image_input.tif"

output="C:\\image_utm.tif"

kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'geoloc': True, "dstSRS":"EPSG:32633"}

gdal.Warp(input,output,**kwargs)
```

The error is:

> TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestName', argument 4 of type 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See examples in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py.

Answer (score 1):

[Gdal Warp](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html) takes the following arguments:

`osgeo.gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSOrSrcDSTab, **kwargs)`

Switch output and input and try again.